# Pandas on Jupyter Notebook VS Code not displaying outputs properly

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Does anyone know how to make Pandas outputs display properly in VS Code Jupyter Notebooks?

As you can see in the image, the values for individual columns in the output of a Pandas DataFrame aren't aligned (whereas they are aligned if you use Jupyter Notebooks directly on a web browser).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the alignment of pandas, I think I have a relatively simple strategy. We can use IPython module.Use the following code to output the results.
`from IPython.display import display`

```
display(df2)
```

Answer (score 9):

[image: Vscode screenshot]

Click on the 3 dotted lines highlighted in the image above. From there its going to prompt you to select text or html. Click HTML, and the full data frame should show up

Comment: This is the answer that I have looked for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a bracket mismatch. Change your code to this:

```
df2.loc[df2['Airport'] == 'ATL', ['Delay']]
```

Comment: Thanks. My question is however around how the output is displaying (e.g., the columns are misaligned with each other). I'll encounter the same issue if say, I run df.info() where columns of the outputs aren't aligned.